# Trash Bin does not work properly

Tags: 20.10, trash

If I show the trash icon in the desktop, there will be nothing on the desktop. In addition, if I right-click the trash bin on the dock, there is no option to empty it. I am running Ubuntu 20.10.

Screenshots:

[image: trash can highlighted - tooltip says "new window"]

[image: desktop icons settings - size standard, show personal folder on, show trash icon on, show mounted drives off]

Comment: What happens when you open the trash? Do you get an "Empty Trash" option there?

Comment: Yes, there is an "Empty Trash" option and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a glitch/bug. Since you mentioned that you can open the trash, and empty it from there, that might be your best option for now.

Also, since you said you are using Ubuntu 20.10, I just want to say that (especially for a new user) I would recommend staying away from using short-term intermediate releases, and only use LTS releases. This is because the latter has a MUCH longer support term (normal releases are only supported for 9 months, while LTS releases are supported for 2 YEARS), more COMMUNITY support (since they have WAY more users), and are more stable than normal releases. A bonus with LTS releases, is that you only have to worry about releases upgrades once every 2 - 5 years, whereas with normal releases, you need to upgrade them every 6 - 9 months (at least, if you want to continue receiving bug fixes and, most importantly, security updates).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.